# Dual-use of Nouns as Proper and Common

Tags: proper-nouns

I request some advice on the grammatical correctness of using a noun in both proper and common forms as part of the same article. The example I am particularly concerned with is related to college majors. Whereas a major like English is always used as a proper noun, even when meant as an area of study, this is less clear for areas of study that are not languages or names of countries.

Let us take the example of the word "finance". Let us suppose I use the sentence "I am taking an exam in finance". In the very next sentence, if I were to say: "This will prepare me for a career in Finance" - does this appear strange to your eyes? Is it in violation of grammar?

To me it appears that interchangeability of capital F is contextually justified  because it is possible to refer to the object in a "commonized" notion, for e.g. on a news channel, and as well as in a proper, standout token, for e.g. on a career website.

Is variation acceptable if it means demonstrating a nuance?

Comment: No, you are way off. English always has a capital E as a language or nationality. However, subjects that are studied are not capitalized unless you are providing the name of a course at an institution: International Finance. Otherwise, it's just lower case.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the usage of "a career in finance" in [Google ngrams](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20career%20in%20finance%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A2017%2Ccd_max%3A2019&lr=lang_en) the only time it is capitalised is when it forms part of an article or book title. When it appears as part of normal text "a career in finance" is all in lower case. Compare a title

> Reach the Top in Finance (The title of a book)

to

> His father wanted him to pursue a career in finance, but his passion
> was for mathematics. (A sentence in a book)

Comment: You are quite right, Peter. All such references to "career in finance" involve lower case 'f'.

The exact phrase I used was not "career in finance", but "path in finance"/"path in Finance". A closely related phrase is "subject of Finance"/"subject of finance". The lower case does make the word look commonplace, contrary to its belongingness to a set of defined subjects.

Answer (score 0):

> The exact phrase I used was not "career in finance", but "path in finance"/"path in Finance". A closely related phrase is "subject of Finance"/"subject of finance". The lower case does make the word look.
>
> Let us suppose I use the sentence "I am taking an exam in finance". In the very next sentence, if I were to say: "This will prepare me for a career in Finance" - does this appear strange to your eyes?

I wouldn’t say “strange”, I would say “wrong” - and it is.

As a surname, the first word of a sentence, or as part of a title of a book or office (Here is Mr Smith, the Director of Finance”), the “f” in finance, which is countable or uncountable, is a lowercase “f”.

In broad terms, the capitalisation of all nouns was more-or-less settled by the end of the 18th century: proper nouns got them, the rest didn’t.

There is the remaining slight difficulty where a noun is a both proper as a title and common as a generality:

“I spoke to Major Smith and he has a problem: majors are leaving the army for business.” Here “Major” is the title as it is attached to a name, and “major” is the common noun.